# How to set cell color and modify its text via datgarid in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am a newbie to VB.Net, and for work I need to use it to develop new UI.

And the problem comes from how to set cell color and modify its text via datgarid,

I use the following code:

```
Me.DataGrid1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid()
Me.SqlDataAdapter1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
Me.SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(Me.DataSet1, "TEST")
Dim myGridTableStyle As DataGridTableStyle = New DataGridTableStyle()
Me.DataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(myGridTableStyle)
myGridTableStyle.GridColumnStyles(1).Width = 120
```

Is there any way to change the font color of column 2(the column I hope to modify) and modify its cell text,

Any instructions is highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few approaches here.

First up, I believe the datagrid is VERY old.

Use a datagridview.

So, say I have a button on a form - to fill the grid, and then I have this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT ID, HotelName, City from tblHotels"
    dim MyTable as datatable = MyRst(strSQL)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MyTable

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint

    Dim dgv As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    Dim MyCell As DataGridViewCell = dgv.Cells("City")

    If (Not MyCell.Value Is DBNull.Value) AndAlso MyCell.Value = "Edmonton" Then
       MyCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua

    End If

End Sub
```

The results are thus this:

[image]

And I always get tired of typing over code to create a data table, so I have this routine.

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL,
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        dt.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

    End Using

    Return dt

End Function
```

And this code:

```
   Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT ID, HotelName, City from tblHotels"
    dim MyTable as datatable = MyRst(strSQL)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MyTable
```

I could have written it as this (one line of code), but I wanted you to better see the data types used in above. So above 4 lines of code can become this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName, City FROM tblHotels")
```

However, sometimes too verbose code when learning hides too much of what I am doing.

But, with that handy dandy MyRst routine? - then often to fill a data grid, a combo box or what not? It only one line of code!!!

Also, while we are at this? Remove your asp.net tag - that is for web development, and the web controls are HUGE, LARGE, VAST, INCREDIBLY, ENORMOUS different then the desktop controls. So your asp.net tag will be a source of confusing here.